# How to log changes from datagridview based on conditions. [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Hi I have a datagridview that have a 1000 rows with information about users which updates every 3 minutes.

I need to log the changes to a different datagridview for every person in the first datagridview.

I've tried to use CellFormatting.

The log is based on 2 conditions : Online / Offline

When the user went Online the new row to the datagridview Date/Time | Name | Login

When the user went offline the new row to the datagridview Date/Time | Name | Exit

[image]

That's what I have tried so far

I'm kind of stuck if you can at least give me the idea of how to do it I will be thankful.

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells(3).Equals("Online✅") Then
            DataGridView2.Rows.Add(Date.Now.ToString("dd:MM:yy hh:mm:ss tt"), row.Cells(2), "Login")
        Else
            DataGridView2.Rows.Add(Date.Now.ToString("dd:MM:yy hh:mm:ss tt"), row.Cells(2), "Exit")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Handle the `CellValueChanged` event to detect the **Status** cells value changes (e.ColumnIndex = 3) and update the second grid accordingly?

Comment: And you need to check the **Value** property: `If row.Cells(3).Value.Equals(...)`

Comment: Whatever thing changes the status of a person from offline to online can also keep the log. It should manipulate datatables, not datagridviews

Comment: The thing is i download this information and i dont manipulate it.